# How to take a complex filter as input from user through command line or to a API?

Tags: python, api, input, command-line-interface

I have a use case where the user can input a complex filter criteria through the CLI. This filter criteria will be applied to a list of iterms

E.g. script_to_run some_args --filter "(age>25 and weight<30) or (not age<18)"

Are there any standardized CLI way by which through we can accept the filter criteria ? Or using some Query language is the only way to input the filter_criteria ? The filter criteria can have a criteria on any one of the attributes of the Object

There is also requirement for a API which also accepts the filter_criteria. Are there any other ways to accept the fitler criteria input other than using a Filter criteria object as input to the API ?

E.g. func(filter_criteria_object)

Comment: How about accepting a configuration file such as .yaml containing all of the filters?

Comment: If you're inputting the filter from the command-line, then the filter will always come in as a string. Simply require the string to be formed in a certain way, and then parse it into whatever datastructure makes the most sense for your application.

Comment: 1. The way your args look is almost pythonic from within itself, you can use regex or even sth. like "click" https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/
2. for api's there will also be a nice packet on pypi ;-)

Comment: @saintlyzero We could use a configuration file. I was looking for a standardized way(if there exists any) by which the filters could be passed

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy How should the filter be passed to a Python API? Is it in the form of string ?

Comment: @AlexanderBrockmeier can you please point me to some packages on PyPI that have this requirements ?

Comment: @SriDivya : I tend to work things out manually (doing it for the first time) as usually it is a Definition of structure in a common sense,
 but you may first check: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/ then: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/ they seem to have a nice documentation, but bring some dependencies!